# How can i solve $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n 3^n}{ (n+3)!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have to solve this sum:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n 3^n}{ (n+3)!}$$
but I really don't have any idea.According to wolfram-alpha I should get $\frac{1}{2}$. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hints:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n3^n}{(n+3)!}=\frac1{27}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n+3)3^{n+3}}{(n+3)!}-3\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3^{n+3}}{(n+3)!}\right)$$

$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\implies e^x=(e^x)'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{nx^{n-1}}{n!}\;\;,\;\;\;\forall\,x\in\Bbb R\;\text{(in fact}\,,\;\forall\,x\in\Bbb C)$$

Comment: Good catch, @user88595. Thanks.

Comment: I managed to finish from here. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

Write as $$a_n=\frac{n3^n}{(n+3)!}=\frac{(n+3-3)3^n}{(n+3)!}=\frac{3^n}{(n+2)!}-\frac{3^{n+1}}{(n+3)!}=t_n-t_{n+1}$$ a telescoping series.

Comment: Shouldn't one of the (n+2)s be (n+3)?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I fixed it.